# How do I use LINQ to select from DataTable, with a list of the required column names

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have some DataTables loaded into memory from various sources (SQL and MS Access), and each dataset has several columns, with only a subset of columns that are the same between each dataset. I'm working on some data synchronization code, and I want to compare these data tables, but only compare them based on the columns they have in common. If I had to I could probably do this with lots of loops, but I want to get more comfortable with LINQ and have more concise code.

Thus far I've managed to get a list of column names from each datatable, and used Intersect to get the list of column names common to both of them, like this:

```
private string[] Common_ColumnNames {
    get {
        // get column names from source & destination data
        string[] src_columnNames = 
        (from dc in _srcDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() 
        select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();

        string[] dest_columnNames = 
        (from dc in _destDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() 
        select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();

        // find the column names common between the two data sets 
        // - these are the columns to be compared when synchronizing
        return src_columnNames.Intersect( dest_columnNames ).ToArray();                
    }
}
```

Now I'm stuck... I need to select all rows from each DataTable, but only with those common columns. In my head I see this working a couple different ways:

1) select all rows from a datatable, and passing in my desired column list string[] variable to tell LINQ what columns I want

2) select all rows from a datatable, and use some lambda function (also fairly new to me) to remove the unwanted columns from each row, and outputing a new datatable with some dropped columns.

Any advice/suggestions on how to pull this off would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I understand you only want to compare the columns they have in common, but why try to strip the columns you don't want, why not just ignore them?  What you're going to end up needing to do is build a new data table with *just* the columns you want, and then take the rows from the other tables and create new rows based off of the new data table and import the values into those new rows.  You can't actually remove columns from a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not LinQ, but it is pretty simple with a DataView

```
string[] commonCols = obj.Common_Columns;
DataView myTableView = new DataView(srcDataTable); 
DataTable srcReducedTable = myTableView.ToTable(false, commonCols);
```

[MSDN refs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6)